# How to pass object of unknown type to function

Tags: c#, types

Is it possible to write a function that would accept *any type* of `object` as a parameter?

something like

```
private bool isItAString(var Input)
{
    string example = "example";
    return Input.GetType() == example.GetType();
}
```

Keyword `var` is **not valid** in this instance and the it expects it to be a specific type of object.

Comment: Just use `object` instead `var`. `Object` is a base type for all types in C#

Comment: `private static bool isItAString(object Input) => Input is string;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let's state the problem:

> > given `Input` object of *arbitrary* type, we should return if it is a `string`

Since all objects in **.Net** are descendants of `object` we can declare `Input` as of type `Object` and put either

```
  // means you can put string value = Input;
  // and value will be assigned  
  private static bool isItAString(object Input) => 
    Input is string;
```

or if we want perform exact check (we want `Input` to be of type `string` and nothing else)

```
  // Or ... => Input == null || ...
  // if we accept null as a valid string 
  private static bool isItAString(object Input) => 
    Input != null && Input.GetType() == typeof(string);
```

please, note, that `var` keyword means *type inference*: we ask .net to *infer* required type instead of typing it explictly:

```
  // data is of type string[] 
  var data = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3} // List<int>
    .Select(x => x.ToString())         // IEnumerable<string>
    .OrderBy(x => x)                   // IOrderedEnumerable<string>
    .ToArray();                        // string[]
```

in your case

```
   private bool isItAString(var Input)
```

.Net can't infer actual `Input` type (is it `object`? `string`?)

Comment: btw, `is string` is an exact type check because `string` is a sealed class, though relying on that knowledge means you should know the class you're testing against, so it is a good thing you've shown the exact type match as well, though I would go with `Input?.GetType() == typeof(string)`, or at least `Input is object &&...` instead of `input != null &&...` [The perfect non-null test](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/11/13/the-perfect-non-null-test/)

Answer (score 2):

```
private bool isItAString(object input)
{
       //Your code here
}
```

`Object(alias object)` is the base class for all objects, so passing it as object will work.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netframework-4.8) type (or its `object` alias, which is preferable), it's a base type of any C#/.NET type

```cs
private bool isItAString(object Input)
{
    string example = "example";
    return Input.GetType() == example.GetType();
}
```

[`var` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) can't be used with method arguments, it's used in method scope to declare implicitly typed variable, otherwise compiler can't infer the type of passed argument.

To check that particular value has the specific type or not, you can use `is` operator and simplify your code to

```cs
private bool isItAString(object Input)
{
    return Input is string;
}
```

Comment: Always prefer `object` over `Object`. In the words of Jared Parsons: [string vs. String is not a style debate](https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2019/04/08/string-vs-String-is-not-about-style.html)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know that, thanks, and already read this article, just show this type and alias to OP

Comment: Well, then, you shouldn't recommend people to use `System.Object`...

Answer (score 1):

If you define function with `bool isItAString(object input)` signature it's like you tell compiler that `input` variable can be instance of **any possible type**.

Detailed explanation:

### .NET object instances always have a type

Firstly, no object instances has really `unknown` type. Any of object instance has base class `System.Object` because all object instances in .NET derived from `System.Object` type.

If you need to know **real** object instance type you can check it by using `.GetType()` method on it, like you do in a question.

### What is difference between `object` and `var`?

#### `object` is an alias for `System.Object` what is a .NET type

You can use it as a base type for your classes:

```cs
public class MyClass : System.Object {}
```

But this code is no sense because all your types already derived from `System.Object` as I mentioned above.

#### `var` is a syntax sugar

It tells compiler to make a variable of type defined after assignment operator (`=`). Like this:

```cs
var str = "Hi, i am string" // Compiler understands that str must be a string.
var i = 25 // Compiler understands, that must be an integer
var f = 25f // f marked as a float. So f will be float.
var result = AnyMethod() // result will be that type which AnyMethod returns
```

So when you have an assignment operator (`=`) you can use `var` because compiler can understand what will be in a variable. But you can't use it as method parameter because compiler can't understand what you trying to place here. Using `object` as method parameter tells compiler that it can be any type. This way you tell the compiler more precisely what to use.